# pvdisplay/pvscan not seeing old disks physical volumes

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

Today I upgraded my FC18 system to FC19 by installing to a new disk.

Once booted I expected to be able to mount the previous boot disk logical volumes but the physical volumes are not visible to pvscan/pvdisplay.
I do see both physical disks with fdisk.

How can I make my old disks' physical volumes visible to pvscan/pvdisplay?

Here's what I did:
Yesterday I was booted off disk1 (LVM) and I could also mount disk2 (LVM with an old FC17).

Today I disconnected disk1 and installed FC19 onto disk2 creating a new filesystem/volumes.

I then reconnected both disks and booted to disk2.

Using fdisk -l I see my old disk /dev/sda and the partition containing my previous volumes: /dev/sda3.

But pvdisplay/pvscan only see the new disk volumes.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Might help if you post the actual output of pvscan. Also, how exactly did you do the install?

Comment: Will do ... I'm not in front of the machine right now and I forgot to enable sshd yesterday ;-)

Comment: I solved my problem last week very simply (but not satisfyingly as I wanted a command-line solution).  By chance I'd setup a vncserver using xfce4 as window manager ... to my surprise I saw my 3T disk on the desktop ... just one click + password away.   I'd have liked to have solved this with the appropriate LVM commands.  I suppose that for some reason lvmetad hadn't recognized the disk (probably wasn't running before I ran xfce4).   There you go ... that might help somebody.